# How to create custome route in laravel 4 for url friendly?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I am using laravel 4 routing for create friendly url for my project. I want to get url with this format:
http://www.mywebsite.com/post/post-slug-content-123 . post-slug-content is my slug, and 123 is my post id.
my route:

```
Route::get('post/{name}-{id}','postController@detail');
```

It not work because laravel detect "post" is my {name} variable, and "slug" is my {id} variable, but i want "post-slug-content" is {name} and 123 is {id}. Any idea ???

Comment: Can you show `postController::detail()`

Comment: Why do you need the slug AND the id for the post? Either one or the other should be enough to identify your post. If you really need both, you need to separate them with  a slash: `Route::get('post/{name}/{id}','postController@detail');`

Comment: If i use slash, it work fine, but i want to keep both for SEO. Maybe i will try slash :D

Answer (score 1):

using `-` wont work and which `-` will it consider breaking in `post-slug-content-123`

if your url is **http://www.mywebsite.com/post/post_slug_content-123**

or **http://www.mywebsite.com/post/postSlugContent-123** try using

```
Route::get('post/{name}-{id}','postController@detail');
```

because you have multiple `-` and it will consider it as a separate URL

Or you may try

1:    `Route::get('post/{nameId}','postController@detail');` where both your name and id is present, further you could break them in your `postController`.

2:    `Route::get('post/{name}/{id}','postController@detail');` this will work fine

or use stackoverflow kind `id followed by name`

3:    `Route::get('post/{id}/{name}','postController@detail');`

you can also use **http://www.mywebsite.com/post/post-slug-content_123** as said by @itachi

4:    `Route::get('post/{name}_{id}','postController@detail');`

Further reference for passing parameters [Here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters).

Comment: you can use, `http://www.mywebsite.com/post/post-slug-content_123`. that's a bettre construct than above.

Comment: that's great @itachi if you dont mind can i add it to my answer?? could be much helpful for future visitors..

Comment: @Ronser feel free to add. the more the options, the better.